# Finding CutSet Matrix from a Circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, graph, circuit-theory

I have the following question

[image]

My answers are

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if my approach and answer is correct to find the Cut Set Matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is right but u did a mistake.

Current in the branch f entering the node 2 while current in branch b leaving the node 2. So your answer for C2 row and b column will be -1 instead of +1.